# .HTACCESS Can't Deny Zip Files

Tags: .htaccess, binaryfiles, zip, apache2.4

I want to deny direct access to my zip files. Which is mean it will give forbidden notice if someone typing the url of the zip files in browser address.

My .htaccess seems like can not deny access to binary files but it can deny php file when I created a test.php in same directory.

It also can't deny access to other binary files e.g .png and .gif

The files are in 4th level deep from root directory.

My .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(zip|php|rar|jpg|gif|png)$">
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from localhost
</FilesMatch>

<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

What's wrong with my server setting?

Comment: You have to check if mod_access is enabled on your server.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar The loaded modul in my php.ini is `mod_access_compat` . My apache version: Apache/2.4.25. Is it related?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. I can deny or redirect some files but not zip files. I've tried blocking everything and the zip files still download.